# Extending ridge around part of an object

Tags: modeling

I would like to extend the raised ridge along all the length of leg to go all the way around the front (the round bit with 5 holes in it) and join up with the edge on the other side of the leg again.

My first thoughts were something along the lines of selecting the vertices around the front, shrinking the selection to the width of the edge then extruding it but I'm unsure how to accomplish this with my limited Blender skills.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

STL file of the design in the link bellow

http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:613877#files

Comment: It all depends on the topology. You may have to re-model it using the original as reference. Include a wireframe for a more helpful answer :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can live with the awful topology of the mesh here are the rough steps to accomplish modeling that ridge:

**Lets start by sanitizing the mesh first**

1. Select these vertex and move your 3D cursor there with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> *Cursor to selected*

[image: Center]

2. Exit edit mode and move the center of the object to the cursor with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > *Origin to 3D cursor*
3. Now that your Arm object has a sane center move it to the scene's origin (coordinate 0,0,0)

**Now lets make the object symmetrical**

4. Add a vertical plane at the object/scene origin

[image]

5. Scale it so it reaches the whole object
6. With **both selected** enter edit mode on the arm object, and **in top view** use the operator *Knife Project* to cut your whole geometry in half. Use the option *cut through* for best results
7. Now delete half of the mesh, making sure you delete all the small faces along the symetry axis

[image]

8. Now you can add a mirror modifier to the object so you only have to deal with half of the mesh and model part of it. Blender will take care of the symmetry

**Modeling the ridge**

9. Now delete this part of the mesh

[image: Deleting]
[image: Deleted]

10. Select the border of the round part an duplicate it with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

[image: Border]

11. Scale in inwards towards the cursor by pressing <kbd>.</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> to scale and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to keep it from scaling in Z direction
12. Separate the scaled edges into a new object with <kbd>P</kbd>
13. Now use the *Knife Project* as described above with the plane to cut it into the mesh
14. Enter edit mode again and you can select these faces

[image: Border faces]

15. Extrude them until they reach the desired height

[image: Extrude]

16. Exit edit mode and add a new plane at exactly the height of the top of the round part

[image: Knife project]

17. Scale it so it covers the whole object and use *knife project* again to cur a new loop on the mesh

[image: New loop]

18. You can now bridge these edges with <kbd>F</kbd> and start closing your geometry

[image]

19. Extrude the sides up. Make sure the surrounding vertex are vertically aligned with the remaining ones so they lign up

[image]

20. Done

[image: Completed]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Duarte. I've not tried it but the end result is exactly what I'm after.

Comment: FYI couldn't get step 6 to work, cut using boolean modifier instead.

Comment: Yeah knife project can be a bit finicky at times. I did forget to mention you have to manually delete the remaining faces afterwards. Edited to reflect that